# saving data from text file to CSV file in python having delimiter as space

Tags: python-2.7, csv, file, text-files

I have a huge report file. I extracted the required data from it into a new file named "new.txt"
I want to save this data in a csv file so that i get the columns and rows properly for each of the headers defined in the file.

I am not able to get it in the proper form as we get it in excel. I am using python 2.7 and want to do this without using pandas package.

SIMPLE_FILE REPORT:

```
CALL            Alias           Severity   File                                                                                                                                                                 Line   Wt   Message
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ACT_99          ACT_99          Warning   /application/XX/VV/2019_2_1/VV/2019.2/data/ip/xm/xm_123/ldm/xm_123.png                                                                                                785    1000 message for this block ( syn_ff ) is ignored by syn
ACT_99          ACT_99          Warning   /application/XX/VV/2019_2_1/VV/2019.2/data/ip/xm/xm_123/ldm/xm_123.png                                                                                                1111   1000 message for this block ( syn_ff ) is ignored by syn
ACT_99          ACT_99          Warning   /application/XX/VV/2019_2_1/VV/2019.2/data/ip/xm/xm_123/ldm/xm_123.png                                                                                                1226   1000 message for this block ( syn_ff ) is ignored by syn
ACT_99          ACT_99          Warning   /application/XX/VV/2019_2_1/VV/2019.2/data/ip/xm/xm_123/ldm/xm_123.png                                                                                                1354   1000 message for this block ( syn_ff ) is ignored by syn
ACT_99          ACT_99          Warning   /application/XX/VV/2019_2_1/VV/2019.2/data/ip/xm/xm_123/ldm/xm_123.png                                                                                                1363   1000 message for this block ( syn_ff ) is ignored by syn
```

Here is my code.

```
import os
import sys
from os import path
import struct

outFile = "new.txt"
new_file = open(outFile, "a+")
new_file.truncate(0)
csv_file = "report.csv"
    
    
reqlen = 0  # minumum length of row
fs = None
def calclens(line):  # calc column widths from header  row
   global fs, reqlen
   rec = []  # all column widths
   ctr = 0
   for i in range(len(line)-1):
      ctr += 1
      if line[i] == ' ' and line[i+1] != ' ':  # new column
        rec.append(ctr)  # add to column width list
        ctr = 0
   rec.append(ctr) # last column
   #print rec
   rec = rec[:-1]  # skip newline  
   rec[-1] += len(line)-i-1  # last column to end of line
   
   
   fieldwidths = rec
   fmtstring = ' '.join('{}{}'.format(abs(fw), 's') for fw in fieldwidths)  # 16s 16s 10s 166s 7s 5s 52s
   fs = struct.Struct(fmtstring)
   reqlen = len(line) 
   
   
def open_file(filename):
    try:
        contents = [] 
        with open(filename, 'r') as f1:
            contents=[line.strip() for line in f1]
        counter = contents.index("MORESIMPLE_FILESORT REPORT:")
        for item in contents[counter:]:
            new_file.write(item+"\n")

        with open("new.txt") as f:
            with open(csv_file,'w') as f2:
                for i,line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
                    if i == 0: continue  #  SIMPLE_FILE REPORT:
                    if line[0] == '+': continue  # skip ++++  line
                    if i == 1: calclens(line)  # header row, calc field positions\lengths
                    #print(len(line))
                    if len(line) < reqlen: line += ' '*(reqlen-len(line))

                    fields = fs.unpack_from(str.encode(line))  
                    
                    fields = [f.strip() for f in fields]  # trim all fields
                    
                    f2.write(','.join(fields)+'\n')  # join fields comma separated


    except Exception,e:
        print str(e)
    exit(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = sys.argv[1]
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    open_file(filename)
```

Comment: That's not CSV, that's a fixed width text file

Comment: @JamesZ how do i save it in excel or csv? i have further processing to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For splitting a **fixed width text** file, you can use the **struct** module.

The below code uses the header row to determine the column position and widths so the header row must be the same length as the data rows and the headers must be aligned correctly.

This code targets Python 2.7. For Python 3, the required change is noted.

```
import struct

ss = '''
SIMPLE_FILE REPORT:
CALL            Alias           Severity  File                                                                                                                                                                  Line   Wt   Message                                            
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ACT_99          ACT_99          Warning   /application/XX/VV/2019_2_1/VV/2019.2/data/ip/xm/xm_123/ldm/xm_123.png                                                                                                785    1000 message for this block ( syn_ff ) is ignored by syn
ACT_99          ACT_99          Warning   /application/XX/VV/2019_2_1/VV/2019.2/data/ip/xm/xm_123/ldm/xm_123.png                                                                                                1111   1000 message for this block ( syn_ff ) is ignored by syn
ACT_99          ACT_99          Warning   /application/XX/VV/2019_2_1/VV/2019.2/data/ip/xm/xm_123/ldm/xm_123.png                                                                                                1226   1000 message for this block ( syn_ff ) is ignored by syn
ACT_99          ACT_99          Warning   /application/XX/VV/2019_2_1/VV/2019.2/data/ip/xm/xm_123/ldm/xm_123.png                                                                                                1354   1000 message for this block ( syn_ff ) is ignored by syn
ACT_99          ACT_99          Warning   /application/XX/VV/2019_2_1/VV/2019.2/data/ip/xm/xm_123/ldm/xm_123.png                                                                                                1363   1000 message for this block ( syn_ff ) is ignored by syn
'''.strip()

with open ('data.txt','w') as f: f.write(ss) # write test file

##################### Main Script #######################

reqlen = 0  # minumum length of row
fs = None

def getmaxlinelen(filename):  # scan file for longest line length
    mx = 0
    with open(filename) as f:
        for ln in f.readlines():
           if len(ln) > mx: mx = len(ln)
    return mx


def calclens(line, mxlen):  # calc column widths from header  row
   global fs, reqlen
   rec = []  # all column widths
   ctr = 0
   for i in range(len(line)-1):
      ctr += 1
      if line[i] == ' ' and line[i+1] != ' ':  # new column
          rec.append(ctr)  # add to column width list
          ctr = 0
   rec.append(ctr) # last column
   rec = rec[:-1]  # skip newline  
   rec[-1] += mxlen-i-1  # last column to end of line (max len data line)
   
   fieldwidths = rec
   fmtstring = ' '.join('{}{}'.format(abs(fw), 's') for fw in fieldwidths)  # 16s 16s 10s 166s 7s 5s 52s
   fs = struct.Struct(fmtstring)
   reqlen = mxlen  #len(line)

mxlen = getmaxlinelen('data.txt')

with open('data.txt') as f:
   with open('data.csv','w') as f2:
       for i,line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
           if i == 0: continue  #  SIMPLE_FILE REPORT:
           if line[0] == '+': continue  # skip ++++  line
           if i == 1: calclens(line, mxlen)  # header row, calc field positions\lengths
           if len(line) < reqlen: line += ' '*(reqlen-len(line)) # line length must match longest length
           fields = fs.unpack_from(str.encode(line))  # python 2
           #fields = tuple(s.decode() for s in fs.unpack(line.encode()))  # python 3
           fields = [f.strip().replace(',','') for f in fields]  # trim all fields
           f2.write(','.join(fields)+'\n')  # join fields comma separated
```

Output (data.csv)

```
CALL,Alias,Severity,File,Line,Wt,Message
ACT_99,ACT_99,Warning,/application/XX/VV/2019_2_1/VV/2019.2/data/ip/xm/xm_123/ldm/xm_123.png,785,1000,message for this block ( syn_ff ) is ignored by syn
ACT_99,ACT_99,Warning,/application/XX/VV/2019_2_1/VV/2019.2/data/ip/xm/xm_123/ldm/xm_123.png,1111,1000,message for this block ( syn_ff ) is ignored by syn
ACT_99,ACT_99,Warning,/application/XX/VV/2019_2_1/VV/2019.2/data/ip/xm/xm_123/ldm/xm_123.png,1226,1000,message for this block ( syn_ff ) is ignored by syn
ACT_99,ACT_99,Warning,/application/XX/VV/2019_2_1/VV/2019.2/data/ip/xm/xm_123/ldm/xm_123.png,1354,1000,message for this block ( syn_ff ) is ignored by syn
ACT_99,ACT_99,Warning,/application/XX/VV/2019_2_1/VV/2019.2/data/ip/xm/xm_123/ldm/xm_123.png,1363,1000,message for this block ( syn_ff ) is ignored by syn
```

Comment: @Mike67..thank you for the idea..I tried this code of yours..everything works well..but the message column is trimmed...just M m m m is displayed for each message statements..What changes do i do to your code?

Comment: Every row in the file must be the same length, including the header row. The header row is used to determine column widths. Add spaces to the header row to match the data row length.

Comment: @Mike67..but the data row may have different length...as the last column is for error messages..

Comment: Answer updated to allow for varying line length (last column only)

Comment: @Mike67..thank you very much...This works...but i get the csv with the last 2 columns combined..Also where is the part in the code that ill have to update incase the other columns are of varying lengths? Also My last 2 columns (Wt and Message col) come as one column...which part of the code takes care of this?   Here is the first 2 rows of csv Rule,Alias,Severity,File,Line,Wt Message SYNTH_89,SYNTH_89,SynthesisWarning,/applics/xilinx/vivado/2019_2_1/Vivado/2019.2/data/ip/xpm/xpm_cdc/hdl/xpm_cdc.sv,785,1000 Initial Assignment at Declaration for ( src_level_ff ) is ignored by synthesis

Comment: The column widths are determined by the header positions. How do you have variable width data?  Does the data go into the next column, under a different header?